# React-Native build Failed Could not download protobuf-java-3.4.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.4.0)

Tags: gradle, react-native, gradlew

getting build failed when running npx react-native run-android 
***error***

---

A problem occurred configuring root project 'AwesomeProject'.
Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   Could not download protobuf-java-3.4.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.4.0)
      Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.4.0/protobuf-java-3.4.0.jar'.

***below is my build.gradle file***

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

[ERROR SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ej8yy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it,
it was due to some Network issue i was not able to access the repository